# Ajax request, when formatting the results, certain elements fail if I add over 2 lines of code

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, spotify

Sorry for the very weird wording of that question, I don't know how to explain it. Basically, I have a text input that acts as a search. Whenever you type a letter or word in, it makes a request to the Spotify API and returns the 5 best matching results; the code is below.

```
$("#SongSearch").keyup(function(){
                  $.ajax({
            url: "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=" + encodeURI(document.getElementById("SongSearch").value) + "&type=track&market=US&limit=5&offset=0",
            headers: {
              'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token
            },
            success: function(InfoGained) {
                           document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML = InfoGained.tracks.items[0].name + ", " + InfoGained.tracks.items[0].artists[0].name;
                           document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML = InfoGained.tracks.items[1].name + ", " + InfoGained.tracks.items[1].artists[1].name;
                           document.getElementById("result3").innerHTML = InfoGained.tracks.items[2].name + ", " + InfoGained.tracks.items[2].artists[2].name;
                           document.getElementById("result4").innerHTML = InfoGained.tracks.items[3].name + ", " + InfoGained.tracks.items[3].artists[3].name;
                           document.getElementById("result5").innerHTML = InfoGained.tracks.items[4].name + ", " + InfoGained.tracks.items[4].artists[4].name;
            }
        });
                });
```

This code correctly calls the API and gets the results. However, when formatting it, if I add more than two of the document.getElementByID... lines in, only two lines work. Example, this works:

```
$("#SongSearch").keyup(function(){
                  $.ajax({
            url: "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=" + encodeURI(document.getElementById("SongSearch").value) + "&type=track&market=US&limit=5&offset=0",
            headers: {
              'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token
            },
            success: function(InfoGained) {
                           document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML = InfoGained.tracks.items[0].name + ", " + InfoGained.tracks.items[0].artists[0].name;
                           document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML = InfoGained.tracks.items[1].name + ", " + InfoGained.tracks.items[1].artists[1].name;
            }
        });
                });
```

But more than two lines of the document.getElementID..., such as the first segment of code listed results in the error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined". Any help is appreciated as I truly have no idea what is causing this. Thanks in advance,
Justin

Comment: 1) Why aren't you using jQuery for those element selections? 2) You should add a sample of the ajax response to your question because you're likely selecting a property from a non-existent array element.

Comment: I guess you really want to check `artists[0].name` for all tracks. Not many tracks have 5 artists.

Comment: Also, try learning how to debug your code. You really have everything in the error message here, and you could probably find the error quickly by inspecting the response with `console.log(InfoGained)` or something similar. It's simply much faster to find it yourself.

Comment: Okay, so, some clarifications. Each call works individually. so if I called tracks.items[4].name + ... it works, so I know that's not the problem. It's only when I call them together/call more than 2 that it gives an error. Also, its getting the artist of each track individually, not getting 5 artists from one track.

Comment: You should create  a loop to loop over the array and handle specific instance inside the loop

Answer (score 0):

I realized after staring at it for an hour or two that InfoGained.tracks.items[4].artists[4].name; is calling the 5th artist for the 5th song. It should have been InfoGained.tracks.items[4].artists[0].name; Thank you everyone, especially Frax, for the help!